# Adding MySQL to PATH in OS X

Tags: macos, mysql

I'm was trying to change the path for mysql so I can merely call mysql in Terminal to start working with my databases.

However, although I edited my `~/.profile` and inserted PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH in there, I still had no luck with calling mysql directly.

Now later on, I deleted everything in the `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` files.

Yet when I call ECHO $PATH, it shows

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin.
```

Why could this be happening when I removed everything from my `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile`?

Also, if it's showing the

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

in my path, why am I still unable to get into MySQL by typing mysql into the Terminal prompt?

Also how can someone set up MySQL to be accessed via Mac OSX Terminal instead of through XAMPP (that's how I got mySQL).

Help would be greatly appreciated.  Someone should really make a semi-decent MySQL manual too...the online documentation doesn't help much at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should find out where XAMPP installed the MySQL executable files. It might be `/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin`; in that case you should use that instead of `/usr/local/mysql/bin`. Otherwise, what you did is correct!